# не работает преобразование byte[] в обьект

Tags: java

имеется задача (Java): преобразовать byte[] в обьект,  дело в том, что я использую UDP клиент и сервер. Соответственно на клиенте я собираю пакет, потом его преобразую в byte[] и отправляю на сервер, там провожу обратную операцию. Но Если клиент находится в одном проекте с сервером все отрабатывает нормально, как только я вынес клиента на другой проект - у меня все падает при преобразовании byte[] в обьект. Вот с такой ошибкой java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:

```
  public static byte[] obj2Byte(Object myObject) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectOutputStream objStream = new ObjectOutputStream(byteStream);
    objStream.writeObject(myObject);
    byte[] arr = byteStream.toByteArray();
    logger.info("Byte[] : {}", Arrays.toString(arr));
    return arr;
}

public static OutputObject byte2Obj(byte[] bytes) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    return (OutputObject) new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes)).readObject();
}
```

Comment: Для десериализации байтов в объект, в classpath должен быть класс этого объекта.

Comment: Не могли бы вы мне пояснить, пожалуйста, что вы имеете в виду, у меня не так много опыта с серилизацией, куда на прописать Класс? Спс

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в том, что я при разделении клиента и сервера поменял структуру пакетов, и поэтому класс не находился!